# Null check problem in kotlin webview file uploading

Tags: webview, kotlin

I'm trying file upload with webview.I m stuck this step.

My full code=

```
override fun onImageChosen(chosenImage: ChosenImage) {
    runOnUiThread(Runnable {
        Log.d("CI:", chosenImage.filePathOriginal)
        if (null == mUploadMessage && mUploadMessageArray == null) return@Runnable
        val result = Uri.fromFile(File(chosenImage.fileThumbnail))
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            mUploadMessage!!.onReceiveValue(result)
            mUploadMessage = null
        } else if (mUploadMessageArray != null) {
            val uris = arrayOfNulls<Uri>(1)
            uris[0] = result
            mUploadMessageArray!!.onReceiveValue(uris)
        }
    })
}
```

Problem code block=

```
val uris = arrayOfNulls<Uri>(1)
                uris[0] = result
                mUploadMessageArray!!.onReceiveValue(uris)
```

When hover to uris ( onReceiveValue(uris) ), it makes the following mistake

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Array<Uri>!
Found:
Array<Uri?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can initialize your uris differently

```
val uris = arrayOf(result)
```

that should not run into nullability issues

problem is (kinda obvious) that kotlin cannot smartcast array assignments, because it cannot be sure that every element of a Nullable type has been assigned to a non-null value

Comment: Thank you so much.You saved my day :)